# ViewPager not loading items after using scrollto(x,y)

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager

I`m using view pager, in previous question i asked about synchronizing two ViewPagers, i've done it with onPageChangeListener()

```
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    mainscreenViewPager.scrollTo(arg0*screenWidth + arg2, 0);
}
```

Now i have 2 ViewPagers synchronized, but when i move the one by scrollTo, it does not load any views.

Comment: When you call `scrollTo` on the `ViewPager`, you're actually moving the entire pager; the children aren't being scrolled.  I'm trying to work out how to do this with a fake drag at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use `mainscreenViewPager.setCurrentItem(arg2);` ?

Comment: hmm, just tried to put on scrollstate changed, on IDLE setCurrentItem(currentPage), but in this case, new item is appearing after some delay, let's say 100 or 200ms, in case i`m using just solid color background. Setting it to 1 (mid item) seems to solve problem, but in case of 3 views. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: and something like `if (!mainscreenViewPager.isFakeDragging()) {
                        mainscreenViewPager.beginFakeDrag();
                    }

                    mainscreenViewPager.fakeDragBy(arg2);`

Comment: tried the thing with fakeDragging but it was slow, and also looked unelegant